# STS - Where is Groovy Installed?

Tags: linux, groovy, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I have installed the latest version of SpringSource Tool Suite and have installed the Groovy and Grails plugins and everything is working fine. I was reading through the basics of Groovy and came to an installation page: http://groovy.codehaus.org/Installing+Groovy

If I do a "find" on my file system I don't come back with anything for "groovysh". Is this because The STS plugin just installed the source code and none of the "extras"? If I want to mess around with "groovysh" do I need to install this Groovy separately (and then manage possibly two sets of Groovy instances on my system)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The groovy inside of STS is not a full groovy distribution.  It contains the compiler jars and all of its dependencies.  If you want command line access to groovy, you need to download it separately from here:

```
http://groovy.codehaus.org/Download
```

In case you are still interested, the groovy jars in STS are located at `springsource/sts-3.0.0.M1/plugins/org.codehaus.groovy_qualifier/lib.